# Twitter Bootstrap and Javascript Alert issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to check for mozGetUsermedia in browser and if its not there return an alert.

I am using Twitter bootstrap Alert JS for the effect
and JS code to check the condition.
But my DOM seems to be broken and even though the condition is false the message is shown.

HTML Code

```
   <div id="gum" >
     <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times</button>
       <h4 class="alert-heading">mozGetUserMedia is missing</h4>
       <p>Do you have the latest<a href="http://nightly.mozilla.org/">Nightly</a> and set
          <i>media.navigator.enabled</i> to true?
       </p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

JS Code

```
    if (!navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
    document.getElementById("gum").style.display = "block";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to hide it by default

```
<div id="gum" class="hide">
```

Since you are using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    if (!navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
        $("#gum").show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nKsMv/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like cream !!